# selecting repetitive data and displaying as a table

Tags: sql, oracle, report, left-join

I'm trying to display data in a cuser table like so

```
a_User
___________________
1, Ben,

2, Joe,

3, Tom,

User_group
______________
1, 1,

1, 2,

1, 3,

2, 2,

3, 1,

a_Group
________________
1, All Access,

2, Customer Service,

3, Finance,
```

So that it pops up like

```
____________________________________________

Ben, All Access, Customer Service, Finance

Joe, null, Customer Service, null

Tom, All Access, null, null
```

instead I'm getting

```
____________________________________________

Ben, All Access, All Access, All Access,
Ben, Customer Service, Customer Service, Customer Service,
Ben, Finance, Finance, Finance
Joe, Customer Service, Customer Service, Customer Service,
Tom , All Access, All Access, All Access,
```

I had been joing an outer left join on it, but I can't get the columns to tie into the descriptions.

```
select su.usernum,
  su.username,
  su.descr,
  su.email,
  sfg1.functiongroup,
  sfg2.functiongroup,
  sfg3.functiongroup
from a_user su
left outer join User_group suf on su.usernum = suf.usernum
left outer join a_group sfg1 on suf.fgroupnum = sfg1.fgroupnum
left outer join a_group sfg2 on suf.fgroupnum = sfg2.fgroupnum
left outer join a_group sfg3 on suf.fgroupnum = sfg3.fgroupnum
where sfg1.FGROUPNUM = 1
  or sfg2.FGROUPNUM = 2
  or sfg3.FGROUPNUM = 3;
```

Any ideas would be really handy,

Feel like I'm missing something really really basic.

Comment: To get your groups from columns to rows you have to work with `pivot` I think. Didn't use it myself so far, but have a look [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

Comment: Hi all, it's oracle 10, hope this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11.2 you can use new function [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

But this is not available in Oracle 10 (which is out of support, btw), you have to write it in a function I guess.